# Spring Boot - Issue in uploading into or downloading from Azure Blob Storage

Tags: angular, spring-boot, file-upload, download, azure-blob-storage

We have a web application which is being built with `Angular 2+` and it consumes data using backend web services which are being built using `Spring boot`.

The backend uses Azure Blob storage for storing images, videos, PDF, etc.

The current process is that the web application(client) is sending Multipart file to the server and the backend will convert `org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile` to `java.io.File` as below

```
public static File convert(MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
  File convFile = new File(file.getOriginalFilename());
  convFile.createNewFile();
  FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(convFile);
  fos.write(file.getBytes());
  fos.close();
  return convFile;
}
```

**Uploading a File into Azure Blob**

```
 ContainerURL  containerURL = serviceURL.createContainerURL("images");
  BlockBlobURL blob = final BlockBlobURL blobURL = 
  containerURL.createBlockBlobURL("nature.png");
  Path sourceFile = convert().toPath();
  AsynchronousFileChannel fileChannel = AsynchronousFileChannel.open(sourceFile.toPath());

                // Uploading a file to the blobURL using the high-level methods available in TransferManager class
                // Alternatively call the PutBlob/PutBlock low-level methods from BlockBlobURL type
                TransferManager.uploadFileToBlockBlob(fileChannel, blob, 8*1024*1024, null, null)
                .subscribe(response-> {
                    System.out.println("Completed upload request.");
                    System.out.println(response.response().statusCode());
                });
        }
```

**Downloading a file** using `BlockBlobURL` and sending path to the client.

```
static void getBlob(BlockBlobURL blobURL, File sourceFile) throws IOException {
        AsynchronousFileChannel fileChannel = AsynchronousFileChannel.open(sourceFile.toPath(), StandardOpenOption.CREATE, StandardOpenOption.WRITE);

        TransferManager.downloadBlobToFile(fileChannel, blobURL, null, null)
        .subscribe(response-> {
            System.out.println("Completed download request.");
            System.out.println("The blob was downloaded to " + sourceFile.getAbsolutePath());
        });
    }
```

In the above method, the `sourceFile` is a file created in the server location and defined using File.createNewFile() method which will create a file in `C:\......\Test\AppData\Local` and a path has to be returned to client end for accessing this file from the mentioned temporary location.

If we deeply look at this process, there are **two uploading processes** : One from the `Web application to our backend` and after creating a file in the server ,`our backend to Azure Storage Blob` and **two downloading processes**: one from `Azure Storage blob to our server` and after creating a file in the server ,from `our server to the Web application`.

Is there any way to find the solution in order to reduce upload and download processes so that the time consumption can be reduced?